# Visual Studio 2022 tabs colorizing not working properly

Tags: visual-studio-2022

I have a relatively large solution with 20+ projects.

I would like the tabs of the files to be colorized by project so I used this settings:

[image]

Unfortunately, Visual Studio 17.3 uses the same color for more than 1 project....

This is 3 different documents from 3 different projects but I see 2 separate colors:

[image]

What else should I set?

Comment: Unsure what someone voted this belongs on another SE site - this is on-topic for SO.

Comment: Maybe someone has a shaky hand...or just didn't know that Visual Studio is an IDE...

Answer (score 3):

It looks like Visual Studio *may* have a slight ineptitude when trying to determine the colors. I had the same issue between my main project and a unit test project (they both had the same color).

Luckily, it looks like you can select the desired color that you want for each project, and after doing so, anytime you open a file in the project, it will now use that color, fixing the issue. To set the color, I recommend the following way (to better see which projects use what color):

1. Click the gear icon at the top right of your tabs
2. Click either place tabs on left or right
3. Right click any tab in the project you wish to change the color of
4. At the bottom of the list, select "Set tab color" and choose a new color.

Repeat steps 3 and 4 for all the projects you need to switch the color of.

Comment: Note - since you have 20+ project, you might run out of colors unfortunately (there appears to only be 16).  It doesn't look like you can set custom colors either.  So you may have to _strategically_ set the colors (perhaps make a few projects that you do not open files from often to the same color).

Comment: So you basically telling that the _developers_ of Visual Studio couldn't create a random color selection (it can be even 256-colors) that can decide which file is from which project. I think, it could be done with a *switch statement*. Should I contribute to the code base of Visual Studio to help them? :)

Comment: @Nestor if you are so inclined!  I was pretty surprised there isn't a custom color picker for this, since other parts of Visual Studio allow you to choose a custom color (see Font and Colors in the options for example).